# How to find CAGR from absolute return in a given duration?

Tags: interest-rate, compound-interest

What is the formula to figure out "Compound Annual Growth Rate (CAGR)" from absolute returns?
Say, if 100% is the absolute return in 5 years tenure, then how would I find what is the CAGR through that 5 years?

Answer (score 2):

Found it after mathematically evaluating it and finding a correlation between the two as -

`CAGR = {[(AR+1)^(1/r)]-1}*100`

where,

CAGR - Compound annual growth rate

AR   - Absolute Return

r    - term in number of years

Since `AR = [(FV/IV)-1]*100`

and `CAGR = [((FV/IV)^(1/r))-1]*100`

where,

FV - Future Value
and

IV - Initial Value